# Chebyshev's inequality's proof details

Tags: probability

I'm studying the proof of the following inequality (Chebyshev's inequality).

$$ \forall \varepsilon>0, \quad \mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|>\varepsilon)\leq \frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\varepsilon^2}.$$

**Proof.**
My professor only proved the case with $X$ is a discrete random variable and did it as follows:

$$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|>\varepsilon)=\sum\limits_{k\in \Delta_X}p_X(k)=(\ast)$$

where

- $\Delta_X$ is the image of $X$.
- $p_X(k)$ is the density of $X$.
- $k$ are the values that satisfy the condition $|k-\mathbb{E}(X)|>\varepsilon$.

So, because of $|k-\mathbb{E}(X)|>\varepsilon$ implies that $\frac{|k-\mathbb{E}(X)|^2}{\varepsilon^2}> 1$, he has

$$(\ast) < \sum\limits_{k\in \Delta_X}\frac{|k-\mathbb{E}(X)|^2}{\varepsilon^2} p_X(k) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\sum\limits_{k\in \Delta_X}|k-\mathbb{E}(X)|^2 p_X(k) \\< \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\sum\limits_{h\in \Delta_X}|h-\mathbb{E}(X)|^2 p_X(h)\leq \frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\varepsilon^2}.$$

(the $h$ in the last step are all of the values in $\Delta_X$).

I cannot understand the last comparison, why $\leq$ and not $=$ ?

Moreover, why the inequality holds with $\leq$ and the inequalities chain is always strict?

Then, I tried to find a case in which equality was valid but I don't think it is possible with that formulation of Chebyshev's inequality.

Could anyone clarify for me a little? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot understand the last comparison, why $\le$ and not $=$ ?

I think $\Delta_X$ represents the set of $k$ satisfying $|k-E[X]| > \epsilon$. (Else the very first step $P(|X-E[X]| > \epsilon) = \sum_{k \in \Delta_X} p_X(k)$ doesn't make sense.) Thus, the inequality you are asking about boils down to summing over a larger set of values for $h$.
$$\sum_{h \in \Delta_X} |h-E[X]|^2 p_X(h) \le \sum_{h} |h-E[X]|^2 p_X(h)= \mathbb{V}(X).$$

> Moreover, why the inequality holds with $\le$ and the inequalities chain is always strict?

You are correct that for *discrete* random variables, your proof actually shows $P(|X-E[X]|>\epsilon) < \mathbb{V}(X) / \epsilon^2$ with a strict inequality. I think Chebychev's inequality is often stated as $P(|X-E[X]| \ge \epsilon) \le \mathbb{V}(X) / \epsilon^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, for absolutely continuous variables the equality could still hold, however, the statement you suggested seems more complete to me and justifies the fact that there is no strict inequality.

Comment: But, if $\Delta_X$ is not the image, where is $h$ in the last sum?

Comment: In my last sum (which is equal to $\mathbb{V}(X)$) the sum is over all $h$ in the image of $X$. @SigmaAlgebra

Comment: Clear! My doubts are satisfied now, thank you very much!